# Swift - Table is blank when scrolling back up

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble with a tableview. When all the way to the end of the table, and the up again, the table content is not loading instantly..

This is the code:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't use screenshots. Just copy and paste the code.

Comment: Just a suggestion. At line 3 you define `tableCell` as `UITableViewCell!` Since in the next few line you are populating the `tableCell` variable, you can declare it as `UITableViewCell` without the `!`. Infact Swift checks that you are always populating the var before using it and does allow it.

Comment: Another suggestion, when possible you should use `let` instead of `var`. Since once assigned `tableCell` does not change, you should declare it as constant, using `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we solved the problem.

The problem was in this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row > 22 && !isAll && indexPath.row == signArray.count-1{
        //This makes the table load inspections in chunks of 24 meaning alot of smaller DB calls instead of one big one and therefore a better user experience since it reduces load times.
        signArray = signArray + appDelegate.dbInterface.findInspectionsBySeriesID(signArray[0].seriesID, offset: numberOfLoads*24, limit: 24)
        numberOfLoads++
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The logic here was a bit flawed and the table got reloaded regardless of whether there was new data or not. Leaving the upper table cells blanks, it is still weird that it only happens when there is no data to get, but changing it to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row > 22 && !isAll && indexPath.row == signArray.count-1{
        //This makes the table load inspections in chunks of 24 meaning alot of smaller DB calls instead of one big one and therefore a better user experience since it reduces load times.
        var newInspections = appDelegate.dbInterface.findInspectionsBySeriesID(signArray[0].seriesID, offset: numberOfLoads*24, limit: 24)
        if !newInspections.isEmpty{
            signArray = signArray + newInspections
            numberOfLoads++
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have same problem that when I scroll Up and hold it for few seconds then Cells get disappear and after release the scroll Cell get automatically appears but I still not find the exact scenario.